# What is the purpose of CD tag in XML data file

Tags: xml, html, tags

Recently I am working on AJAX XMLHttp request concept, encountered the CD tag while loading the XML data file in JavaScript function, as

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
<TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
<ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
<COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
<COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
<PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
<YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

Please explain the purpose of CD tag here, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Xml dialects are customized by the application.  Without knowing where you got an xml snippet from there is no way for anybody to answer this.  There is no standard definition for that tag.

Comment: The snippet is from w3schools. The purpose of the CD tag is to enclose the album tags.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no answer to that question without knowing the definition of the XML dialect that it comes from.

XML (e**X**tensible **M**arkup **L**anguage) is an extensible language which means that you define your own tags.  In some sense, XML is a meta-language - it isn't really a language, but a set of rules for constructing a language.  There is no universal set of tags (and only a very few universal attributes - `xml:lang` for an example of one).  The meaning of tags depends entirely on the application.  There are many defined XML dialects that assign specific meaning to particular tags (XSLT, Docbook, etc).

That particular case is probably from an example published somewhere to show XML structure or to use to demonstrate manipulation of XML.  In this particular case, one could infer that this is meant to be a catalog of compact discs and that each disc is enclosed in a *CD* tag, but that is only an educated inference.  What it really means is up to the author of that particular dialect.

Comment: @GirriajGupta You're welcome.  If this was helpful to you, please consider accepting the answer.  You are not obligated to do so, but it will award the poster and yourself a small amount of reputation, and mark the question as answered.  Additionally, you may upvote any answer that you think is particularly helpful, both on your own questions and on anybody else's.

Answer (score -1):

In your code CD tag represents one item Compact Disc. All detail for particular compact disk is between CD tags.